# How get age column from birthday column in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have birthday column in the table of users. Database is postgresql. I want to filter users by age. How do it in sqlalchemy.
In raw sql it looks like:

```
SELECT name, birthday
FROM User
WHERE date_part('year', age(birthday)) <= 30
```

Comment: You probably want to read [this piece of documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#functions).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from sqlalchemy import extract, func

session.query(User.name, User.birthday).filter(extract('year', func.age(User.birthday)) <= 30)
```